# How can a game prevent people from running multiple instances of itself?

Tags: software-engineering

Starcraft II restricts me from running multiple instances, but if I run the second instance [sandboxed in Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/), it works. What might account for this?

How might I replicate this behavior for my own games?

Answer (score 15):

Aside from Starcraft 2, the general answer to this is: Acquire (and lock, if the acquisition itself isn't already equivalent to locking) a specific resource from the operating system. Exit the game if the acquisition/locking fails. Example of such resources are:

1. Specific TCP or UDP ports.
2. Mutually exclusive locks ("mutexes") or semaphores (those two are often related on OS level)
3. Files (log files are often the most obvious choice)

On the top-end, most pain-in-the-ass for the customer way, specialised hardware which (sometimes necessarily, like for some robotic control components) can only be used exclusively by a single thread can be used this way, too.

Comment: Also it may be useful to keep in mind possible security complications: "[A single-instance program is it's own denial of service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/06/20/639479.aspx)".

Comment: Since it works in sandboxie, it's probably not the first.  2 or 3 are good possibilities, taking a look at what files are open to their processes will probably pinpoint it.

Comment: @Doug-W I don't see how it working in sandboxie rules out #1.

Comment: @AttackingHobo unless I miss understood the complexity of sandboxie, wouldn't the fact that a port is bound outside sandboxie preclude it from binding within?  Or does sandboxie provide a virtual interface for each program running inside of it?

Comment: @Vigil As far as I'm concerned, you may quote Raymond Chen all day, but please don't add grammatical errors to his quotes. :P (Just copy/paste them instead.)

Answer (score 4):

I recommend the mutex approach, but:

Another method that is often used is simply checking if another process with the same name is running.

The advantage is that it's ridiculously easy - you don't have to worry about file permissions or know what a mutex is.  The downside is, you'll get a false-positive if a *different* program called `starcraft2.exe` is running on the machine.

Comment: Hehe, or if the user decides to rename the program.

Comment: @Jonathan: Then don't hardcode the executable name...

Comment: I meant more like, what if the user copies the program and renames it & runs it twice?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C++ and the Windows API, one way you can do is using `FindWindow`, where you can pass parameters like the class name and/or the window name. Then if you find a match, just exit your program before you even load or create a window.